# How ToExtract and Parse HTML Table using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i want to Extract  specific data  from  table tag how can i do this.

```
public class Parse1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(http://allahabadhighcourt.in/casestatus/caseDetailA.jsp?type=BAIL&num=12801&year=2013").get();

for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
     for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(2)")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
        System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "->" + tds.get(1).text());
     }
}
   }  

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract and Parse HTML Table using Jsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853002/extract-and-parse-html-table-using-jsoup)

Comment: You url is incorrect.